# Ideas for a new scenario (mutant style)

Tags: world-building, adventure-writing, plot-hooks

My first question here, let me know if I can improve my question. Or if I'm asking in the wrong place. :)

I'm planning start a modern campaign with my friends and I would like to create a "mutant" theme in this scenario.

All the players will, at beginning of the campaign, discover a random special ability (they won't choose) and their normal life will change after that (for better or worse). Regardless the system I will use, my real problem is create this scenario.

I mean, my only references are Heroes (tv serie) and, of course, X-men. But I really don't want to create super-heroes and super-villains (like X-men). I will try to make more realistic as possible. And the powers won't be that overpower, at least not at beginning.

I already decided a few general things about the scenario:

- The world does not know people with powers exists, they are less than 0,1% of population.
- Most of them try to hide their abilities, so they can have a normal
  life (or get advantage of normal people)
- Some groups of normal people know their existence. Some of them want
  to kill them all, others just want to understand their powers and
  make research.
- All those groups, not necessary knowing each other, agree that is
  better for the world not know about it (for reasons like:
  mass panic > paranoia > segregation > rebellion > war).
- There is groups of people with abilities trying to make the world a
  better place, but, at same time, avoiding being caught.
- And others people with abilities exploiting their powers at most, to
  get profit.

With that in mind, I can create a decent scenario. At the moment, I will try to focus in how each player's life before the powers is changing. Family, work, friends, personal goals... They will try to live a normal life? They will abandon everything if, for some reason, their life is at risk? And I will try to see what path that player is choosing (good, bad, neutral...).

Doing that, my idea is make each adventure taking like 1-2 days or so in story time. So they will know each other in a intense way (probably risking their lives) and, when the plot ends, they go back to their regular life. After months, a new plot appears starting with one or more players and they need to reunite again and help each other out.

But I'm still thinking I did not cover everything... I would like to hear more ideas about that. Plots, environment, politics, maybe another reference that I could read and get more ideas? What should I do if a player decides to go against the others (be bad, when everyone decided to be good, or vice versa)? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. As written this question would result in a list of ideas with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This site is focused on looking for best answers that solve specific, concrete problems. If you don't have a more concrete problem to solve around this issue, you may want a [forum instead](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) where you can discuss and brainstorm together.